# Best approach to explode high values

Tags: php

What's best approach to explode and separate high numeric values so it will be displayed in more legible way?

For example
`100000000` should be converted to `100 000 000`, or `10000.00` to `10 000.00`

Comment: In america they use `,` for seperation. In my country it's `.` - So 100.000.000 or 10,000,000. This is however not a programming question.

Comment: what did you try in php?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php) function.

```
$number = 1234.56;

number_format($number, 2, ',', ' '); // 1 234,56
```

Answer (score 3):

As it's tagged as PHP you are looking for function called

```
number_format()
```

More details how to use it in documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$value = 100000000;
echo number_format($value , 0, ' ', ' ');
```

Output:- `100 000 000`

Answer (score 0):

`number_format()` function will accept one, two, and four arguments. Not three. and it  works as follows:

```
// formatting with ","
$number = 1234.56;
var_dump(number_format($number));   // 1,235


//formatting with decimals
$number = 1234.56;
var_dump(number_format($number, 2));   // 1,235.56


//formatting with thousands seperator
$number = 1234.56;
var_dump(number_format($number, 2, '.', ''));   // 1235.56
```